# Update a variable through ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, variables, jframe, actionlistener

I am having problems with updating a String with a ActionListener, or in a push of a button. Let me show a summarized piece of the code:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
//Importing some data from the main Class
public static String ques = Main.getQues();
public static String QuesExtra = Main.getQuesExtra();

    //More GUI Stuff here

    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit!");
    btnSubmit.setBounds(557, 295, 117, 42);
    contentPane.add(btnSubmit);

    textField1 = new JTextField();
    textField1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    textField1.setBounds(214, 301, 256, 36);
    contentPane.add(textField1);
    textField1.setColumns(10);

    textField2 = new JTextField();
    textField2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    textField2.setColumns(10);
    textField2.setBounds(480, 281, 55, 36);
    contentPane.add(textField2);

    lblQuestion = new JLabel(ques, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblQuestion.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    lblQuestion.setBounds(10, 30, 664, 72);
    contentPane.add(lblQuestion);

    SubmitHandlerClass submithandler = new SubmitHandlerClass();
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(submithandler);
}

private class SubmitHandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        answer1 = textField1.getText();
        answer2 = textField2.getText();

        if (ques.equals("a")){
            if (answer1.equals("a")) {
                check = "Correct";
            } else {
                check = "Wrong";
            }
        } else if(ques.equals("b")){
            if (answer1.equals("b")) {
                check = "Correct";
            } else {
                check = "Wrong";
            }
        }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("Your Answer is " + check + "!"));

        new Main().random();
        //I'm guessing the problem Lies here
        String ques = Main.getQues();
        String QuesExtra = Main.getQuesExtra();

        lblQuestion.setText(ques);
        lblQuesextra.setText(QuesExtra);

    }
}   
}
```

Firstly, let me explain a little bit about the main class. The main class include java.util.Random which would provide the GUI class with random questions for the user. The question is then transferred to the GUI class to update the JLabel. On the click of the "Submit" button, it would check if the answer is correct. In addition, it would help generate a new question and setText would then update the JLabel.

Everything works except the question doesn't seem to update although the JLabel changes. It's pretty hard to explain so I'll leave it in point form.

- JLabel Displays the question "a"
- User inputs "a" as a answer and submits it
- Therefore, a MessageDialog appears saying the answer is correct
- The random method would chose a second question for the user
- JLabel get's updated to the new question "b"

*if the user inputs "b" (Which is should be correct)*

- MessageDialog would say that the answer is wrong.

*if the user inputs "a" (Which is should be wrong)*

- MessageDialog would say that the answer is correct.

From this I can conclude that for some reason the String doesn't actually change thus the if else statement sees it still as "a" instead of "b" and checks the answers against the wrong question.

I am not too sure if my understanding is right, but after some try and error I figured out that is the problem. I have also tried to force change the String by replacing the other code with `ques = "b"` and it still does not work.

That's the best I can elaborate for now, but if you are still unclear feel free to ask any questions so I can improve my question. Also, thanks in advance for taking a look a hopefully coming up with a solution to fix the problem.

Comment: Consider posting a minimal code example that demonstrates your problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). This will allow us to run your code and modify it and perhaps even correct it.  Please read the link before replying as it supplies many important details on the SSCCE requirements. Also, your design has a bad code smell with over-use of static fields.

Comment: Also, you'll not want to hard-code your correct answers, or questions. This should be part of the data, not the code.